# Is there a way to find size class in landscape mode when device is portrait?

Tags: swift, size-classes

I know I can find the current size class from `traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass` but I want to know what the `sizeClass` will be when a device is in different orientation.

Is there a way to figure it out?

Comment: It might be helpful if you update your question with the actual problem you are trying so solve. There may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Well, there may be a better way… but the only thing I can think of is reading the device type and encoding the values manually. So you would know that an iPhone 14 would be regular width and compact height in landscape mode, etc.,